# How to strip HTML <p> tags injavascript without using regex

Tags: javascript, jquery

I reading a text using .Html() and copying the content to the textarea.  I don't want to keep anything except the `<br/>`  tag wich I intend to replace to keep the new line formatting.  Basically, I have `<p> <p/>` which I no more want to keep when I am copying to the textarea.  How can I do that without using regex expression?

```
$("#myText").val($.trim($(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find('.mytext').html().replace('<br/>', '/r/n'));
```

---

Comment: Maybe this link will help: http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/remove-tags

Comment: @Baszz `replace(/(<[^<>]*>)/g, "")` that plugin uses regex

Comment: The standard JavaScript string `.replace()` function takes a regex _or_ a plain string in the "what-to-replace" parameter. But why no regex? What if in future you have a paragraph tag with some attributes specified, e.g., `<p class="someclass">`? Also, shouldn't you replace each `<p>` with a newline (as you do for `<br>`)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use additional `replace` commands chained.

```
.replace('<p>', '').replace('</p>', '');
```

However this won't be the most efficient method of doing things, as you will do three `replace`s where a single one with a regular expression would have sufficed.

Comment: I am using text = text.replace(/<P>/g, '').replace(/<P/>/g, ''); but it`s giving me error on replace(/<P/>/g, '');  Why is that so?

Comment: @learning - you need to quote the slash in `<p/>`.  It's treating it as the end of the regexp, which means that the following characters mean nothing.  To escape, use a double backslash, as in `<p\\/>`.  See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript) on SO for more info.

Comment: This doesn`t seem to work in Chrome and Firefox but it is working in IE8.o.  Do you have any idea how to make it work in Chrome and Firefox as well?

Answer (score 2):

For more generic jQuery tag-stripping, the `.text()` function automatically strips tags even across child HTML elements.

Comment: You can always shimmy on over to the jQuery documentation for more details. Coincidentally, they've got a good example for `.text()` over there. http://api.jquery.com/text/